# Bootstrap container-fluid fixed in screen size

Tags: css, screen

I want to build a page that will load 11 images.

The images need to be 3 in first row, 5 in second row and 3 in third row.

This images are big, but all of then should be seen in screen, so I try div with container-fluid class, so all images fill up each div col.

The problem is that even setting height and/or max-height, or setting 33% for each row, the heigth are always bigger than the screen.

The code is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can I do to all images been auto resized to fit in screen and been seen at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I found how.

Basically you just need to ensure that all is one row and setup class for each device size, something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">             
              <a href="\"> <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
         </div>
    </div>
    and so on...
```